# Marginal Distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Let X be a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let us further assume that $\mu \sim \mathcal N(\mu_p, \sigma_p^2)$ and its prior distribution is $\pi(\mu)$. The variables $\mu_p$ and $\sigma_p^2$ are assumed to be either known or estimated. Find the marginal distribution of the given random variable. I am struggling with this question, any help would be greatly appreciated. Even just a hint on how to start this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

The marginal distribution of $X$ is given by :

$$m(x)=\int \pi(x|\mu)\pi(\mu) \mathrm{d}\mu\,, $$  where $\pi(\mu)$ is the prior distribution and $\pi(x|\mu)$ is the sampling distribution.

Comment: This answer stops short of actually answering the question that was asked, and fails to exploit some simple well-known properties of the normal distribution.

Answer (score 2):

The *conditional* distribution of $X$ given $\mu$ is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  So the conditional distribution of $X-\mu$ given $\mu$ is $N(0,\sigma^2)$, and no $\mu$ appears in that last expression: $N(0,\sigma^2)$.  Hence $X-\mu$ is independent of $\mu$!  So $X$ is the sum of two **independent** random variables: $X-\mu$ which is distributed as $N(0,\sigma^2)$, and $\mu$, which is distributed as $N(\mu_p,\sigma_p)$.  Hence $X \sim N(\mu_p,\sigma^2+\sigma_p^2)$.  That's the marginal distribution of $X$.